# Trying to update a class variable from within an Android's Response.Listener's `onResponse` method

Tags: java, android, android-volley, java-threads, jsonresponse

I'm trying to set a class variable from within this overriden method. I understand that this is executed in another thread. If I output it from there, I get the value. If I output it in a method below, values are null.

How to go about setting this class variable in a correct way?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] mRestTitles = new String[2];

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject rootObject = response.getJSONObject("_embedded");
                        JSONArray users = rootObject.getJSONArray("users");

                        for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject o = users.getJSONObject(i);
                            mRestTitles[i] = o.getString("firstName");

                            Log.d("item", mRestTitles[i]);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("erro", error.toString());
                }
            }

    );

    queue.add(request);


public ArrayList<Entry> generateEntryList(){

    String[] entryTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.entry_names);
    String[] entryDescriptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.entry_description);

    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < mRestTitles.length; i++){
        // mRestTitles is here null
        Log.d("foo", mRestTitles[i]);
        entries.add(new Entry(mRestTitles[i], entryDescriptions[i]));
    }

    return entries;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to handle this situation:

1) Create your own interface with parameter as your variable ( That has to be used anywhere)

```
public interface yourInterface
{
    public void updateMyVariable(String variable);
}
```

2) Implement that interface where ever you want to receive the variable's value.

```
@override
public void updateMyVariable(String variable)
{
  //get the value here 
}
```

3) Invoke the interface from your onResponse Method as soon as you get the variale's value like this.

```
yourInterface.updateMyVariable( VariableToBeUsed );
```

> Make sure yourInterface object has the reference to the context of the
>   activity that is implementing/overriding the function.